# SAP PO integration

Tags: sql-server, sap-pi

I am having a project that need to extract data from SAP PO to SQL Server and vice versa. The task will be executed one per day, so we plan to use SQL Agent to control the scheduled job.

What is the best method to input data into SAP PO and vice versa?

I googled it and found some method to integrate with SAP but none of them talk about SAP PO.

Answer (score 1):

If you means "Process Orchestration" under PO, so [MS] SQL could be JDBC data source/target. SAP PO itself is not data source, but middleware, so in most cases it has no business data, but program code and message exchange statistical data.

Explain your requirements more detail.